# I dont know why its giving me the die() message

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to search the database to see if the username is already taken. I know there are a lot of stuff on 'how to check' but I would like help on why it is giving me the `die('Error getting information');` message. I'm not sure if its my query or what.

This is my PHP

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$username = $_POST["username"];

$sqlget = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE $username = username";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlget) or die('Error getting information');
$sql_row_count = mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);


if ($sql_row_count > 0) {
  echo 'Records found!';
} else {
  echo 'No records found!';
}
```

So when I enter a username and click submit it will show me "Error getting information" Could you guys tell me why?

Comment: **exectly** because you're using die, instead of proper error reporting

Comment: @YCS, I can half understand why this has been closed but the question asked wasn't actually how to get the error, it was whats causing the error..

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why its been duped as that question either. Im not asking how do I get the error im asking why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sqlget = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE $username = username";`

Should be:

`$sqlget = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";`

Though you should bind the $username as you're vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Comment: This worked omg thank you so much i've been searching for a way for the past 12hrs. Thanks again! I will mark it answered as soon as I can!

Comment: p.s there is some validation to stop the injection i just didn't add it to the question

Comment: Yes there is. Have a read up on mysqli bind param.

Comment: What im saying is don't worry about it. Thanks again.